# UV Maps and inconsistent shading issues

Tags: uv

I'm having some difficulty with a texture sheet I created for my model.  I created UV maps but rotated some 90 degrees so that they would fit on a 4096X4096 Texture sheet.

Now I'm getting inconsistent lighting when I export. Are all the islands supposed to be oriented in relation to one another?

Not sure why rotating various parts of a  UV maps of a mesh would effect lighting issues.

Comment: That indeed sounds strange.
What do you mean with export? As .blend file? To another program? "Are all the islands supposed to be oriented in relation to one another?" - No except that they shouldn't overlap. Did you bake your textures previously? (then that might have been the problem, because the lighting is set before you rotated) Uploading some screenshots or a .blend file might help to solve the problem ;)

Comment: I tried rebaking the mesh (AO) and this did not fix the shading issue.  I used the project from view to create UV maps for both top and bottom of my mesh. When I oriented the UV maps on my texture sheet they are facing opposite directions and this gives me the inconsistent shading. If I orient them the same way the issue seems to fix iteslf but this would require reworking the entire texture sheet.  I tried recalculating normals as well but not sure why this is happening.  Blender render does not show this inconsistency.  Its just present ingame.

Comment: "ingame"?. What game are you reffering to? Are you exporting to an external game engine?

Comment: This sounds like an interaction with a tangent space normal map.  Rotating UVs will affect one, because the tangent these UVs are measured relative to is the UV tangent-- the direction of increasing U.  Are you using a normal map?